# Maneira mais simples de converter array 2d em lista de lista C# Winforms

Tags: c#, array, winforms, lista

Busco uma maneira mais simples de converter um array bidimensional
`double[,] myArray` em uma lista de listas `List<List<double>>myLists`. Quando preciso converter um array simples em uma lista simples, posso usar simplesmente o método ToList() do array `myArray.ToList()`. Já para um array bidimensional não encontro nenhum método parecido. Fiz a conversão percorrendo o array 2d através de dois blocos `for()` porém gostaria de uma maneira mais simplificada de fazer isso.

**Método que gostaria de simplificar**

```
List<List<double>> myLists = new List<List<double>>();
double[,] myarray = (double[,])reader.GetValue(0); //reader é preenchido pelo meu database

for (int i = 0; i < myarray.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    List<double> tempList = new List<double>();
    for (int j = 0; j < myarray.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        tempList.Add(myarray[i, j]);
    }
    myLists.Add(tempList);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tentei algumas maneiras de fazer, mas todas eu precisei usar pelo menos 1 laço for.

Basicamente o que eu fiz foi converter a matriz para um vetor que seria um `IEnumerable<double>`, dessa forma eu consigo tratar usando `Linq`.

```
List<List<double>> listaFinal = new List<List<double>>();

double[,] matriz = new double[,] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 }, { 10, 11, 12 } }; 
IEnumerable<double> vetor = matriz.Cast<double>();
int skip = matriz.GetLength(1);

for (int i = 0; i < matriz.GetLength(0); i++)
{
   listaFinal.Add(new List<double>(vetor.Skip(i * skip).Take(skip)));
}
```

Ou

```
for (int i = 0; i < matriz.GetLength(0); i++)
    listaFinal.Add(new List<double>(matriz.Cast<double>().Skip(i * matriz.GetLength(1)).Take(matriz.GetLength(1))));
```

Eu sugiro que você não altere o seu código se você se preocupa com performance, a não ser que você quer apenas diminuir o seu código.

Answer (score 1):

A maneira mais "simples" (se é que isso pode ser chamado de simples) é utilizando LINQ:

```
        // Dados
        var myarray = new double[,] { { 3, 2, 1 }, { 6, 5, 1 }, { 5, 9, 0 }, { 4, 6, 8 } };

        // Conversão, coloquei em mais linhas pra facilitar a leitura, mas pode ser colocado em uma linha apenas, apesar de eu não recomendar isso
        var listaDeListas = Enumerable.Range(0, myarray.GetLength(0))
            .Select(x => Enumerable.Range(0, myarray.GetLength(1))
                .Select(y => myarray[x, y]).ToList()).ToList();

        // Mostrando o resultado
        // 3 2 1  / 6 5 1  / 5 9 0  / 4 6 8
        listaDeListas.ForEach(x => { x.ForEach(y => { Console.Write($"{y} "); }); Console.Write(" / "); });

        // Pausa no console
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Mas como o Marcos Junior comentou, se o problema for performance não creio que seja um boa ideia.
Tente sempre priorizar a legibilidade do código.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar um [iterador](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/iterators) que [enumere](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable?view=net-6.0) os elementos de cada linha de seu array e então adicione cada uma dessas linhas a lista com o resultado.

O método usado é adaptado dessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801990/how-to-get-a-dimension-slice-from-a-multidimensional-array) no [Stack Overflow EN](https://stackoverflow.com/).
Aqui o método `IEnumerable<double> SliceRow(double[,] array, int row)` aceita um array e um inteiro que indica o índice da linha do array a ser enumerada.
O método itera pelos índice dos elementos da linha a ser enumerada com [`Array.GetLowerBound()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.array.getlowerbound?view=net-6.0) e [`Array.GetUpperBound()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.array.getupperbound?view=net-6.0) e com a instrução [yield](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) retorna cada elemento individualmente.

O código se consiste em iterar a cada linha do array `myarray`, a enumerar os elementos, os converter numa lista e adicionar essa lista a `myLists`.

Esse exemplo termina imprimindo os elementos de `myLists` como uma forma de conferencia visual:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


class Program
{
  //Declara o método iterador.
  public static IEnumerable<double> SliceRow(double[,] array, int row)
  {
    //Do primeiro ao último índice i de um linha...
    for (var i = array.GetLowerBound(1); i <= array.GetUpperBound(1); i++)
    {
        yield return array[row, i];                //...retorna o elemento i da linha...
    }
  }

  public static void Main()
  {
    double[,]  myarray = new double[,] {{ 3, 2, 1 },{ 6, 5, 1 },{ 5, 9, 0 },{ 4, 6, 8 }};
    List<List<double>> myLists = new List<List<double>>();
    //Para cada linha i de myarray...
    for(int i = 0; i < myarray.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
      myLists.Add(SliceRow(myarray, i).ToList());   //...enumera os elementos da linha, os converte em lista e a adiciona a myLists.
    }
    //Imprime o resultado apenas para conferência visual.
    foreach (var l in myLists)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", l));
    }
  }
}
//3, 2, 1
//6, 5, 1
//5, 9, 0
//4, 6, 8
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/A2DToList#main.cs)</sup>